# How do I mock Node.js running time operating system in a unit test for `Path` module?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, path, mocking

The default operation of the `node:path` module varies based on the operating system on which a Node.js application is running. [See more](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#windows-vs-posix)

```js
// On POSIX:
path.basename('C:\\temp\\myfile.html');
// Returns: 'C:\\temp\\myfile.html'

//On Windows:
path.basename('C:\\temp\\myfile.html');
// Returns: 'myfile.html'
```

In order to test the `POSIX` and `Windows` operating systems on my local machine, I have to mock the Node.js running time operating system in a unit test.

Is there a way to do this?  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I get a solution with [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire):

```js
const path = require('path');
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

const rule = proxyquire('../../../lib/rules/no-index', {
  path: { ...path.win32, '@global': true },
});
```

With the help of `proxyquire`, I can mock the `path` lib and make it behaves like on Windows when running on my mac without changing my source code.